# Authorization causes bloated controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, testunit

I've got a filter which ensures that only super admins can access a particular action:

```
before_action :require_super_admin

def index; end
```

In my controller tests I've got:

```
test "should let super admin access index" do
  login_super_admin
  get :index
  assert_response :success
end

test "should NOT let normal admin access index" do
  login_normal_admin
  get :index
  assert_response :redirect
end

test "should NOT let user access index" do
  login_user
  get :index
  assert_response :redirect
end

test "should NOT let guest access index" do
  login_guest
  get :index
  assert_response :redirect
end
```

That's four tests to ensure that only a super admin can access the index. Is there a better way of testing this? Does anyone else ever find themselves doing this sort of thing? I run into it every time I build a rails app.

Comment: In my experience, tests are always pretty "bloated" like this. There are tons of possible permutations you have to check even for simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'shoulda-context'

# In test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  def make_sure_authorization_kicks_in
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    assert_equal "You are not authorized to perform this action.", flash[:error]
  end
end

# In controller tests
context "NOT Super Admin" do    
  # saves a lot of typing 
  teardown { make_sure_pundit_kicks_in }

  context "just NORMAL ADMIN" do
    setup { login_normal_admin }
    should("NOT get index"){ get :index }          
    should("NOT get new"){ get :new }
  end

  context "just normal USER" do
    setup { login_user }
    should("NOT get index"){ get :index }          
    should("NOT get new"){ get :new }
  end
end
```

This is much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared examples

```
shared_example "allow super admins" do |actions|
  actions.each do |action|
    it "should let super admin access #{action}" do
       login_super_admin
       get action.to_sym
       assert_response :success
    end
  end
end

shared example "deny non super admins" do |actions, users|
  actions.each do |action|
    users.each do |user|
      it "should let not let #{user} access #{action}" do
         send("login_#{user}")
         get action.to_sym
         assert_response :redirect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in your tests that need authorization check, you can do

```
it_behaves_like "allow super admins", ["index"]
it behaves_like "deny non super admins", ["index"], ["normal_admin", "user", "guest"]
```

PS: I haven't tested this. This is just to give you an idea

Comment: ha, thanks, I'm on test-unit - your code is for Rspec :) - I've decided to use shoulda-context, and accept the extra tests